# How to replace a shape with an image in Canvas js?

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, litterallycanvas.js

I am trying to replace the ellipse shape below with an image file.

```
/* this is the image variable I'm trying to use to replace the shape*/
var img = new Image();
img.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
    canvas.drawImage(this, 0, 0, 400, 400);
}, true);
img.src="img/crystal.png";

/* this is circle shape I'm trying to replace*/

    stroke(0);
    fill(175);
    ellipse(xpos, ypos, 32, 32);
}
```

Comment: If nothing else works, you can always try this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10038668/css-js-for-circular-cropping-of-an-image

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're asking, could you post more of your code? I don't know litterallycanvas.js but `stroke()`, `fill()` and `ellipse()` are global methods? Are you calling them like that? do you want your image to fill the ellipse shape or just to be at the same position as your actual ellipse ?