# How to make the image transparent around the circle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a image cropping popup where the wrapper has a sphere in it. My target is to make the image transparent to the wrapper except the sphere inside the wrapper.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <figure>
    <img src="https://iso.500px.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/andre_cover.jpg"/>
  </figure>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper{
  height: 300px;

  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}
figure{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

figure img{
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/benjaminthomas/L1dsaqL3/1/)**

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10038668/css-js-for-circular-cropping-of-an-image

Comment: Or a solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/13u5z2mg/3/

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @ketan my expected output is the center sphere should not transparent the image whereas the outside the sphere should show the image transparent.

Comment: Check http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/ It may help you

Comment: @ketan the link is to clipping the image i dont want to clip the images rather i want the image to transparent (opacity: 0.5) outside the sphere

Comment: @Benjamin go to below in that page there is one example which display transparent outside area. not clipping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check following which is your expected output.

```css
img {
  mask: url(#masking);
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0" y1="00%" x2 ="0" y2="100%">
      <stop stop-color="black" offset="0"/>
      <stop stop-color="white" offset="1"/>
    </linearGradient>

    <mask id="masking" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <rect y="0.3" width="1" height=".7" fill="url(#gradient)" />
      <circle cx=".5" cy=".5" r=".35" fill="white" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
</svg>

<img src="https://iso.500px.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/andre_cover.jpg" width="568">
```

**[Reference link](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/)**

**Second Solution:**

Using div you can do like following way.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}
div{
    position:relative;
    width:450px; height:300px;
    overflow:hidden;
    left:0;
}
div:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    left:155px; top:25px;
    border-radius:50%;
    width:150px; height:150px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1000px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}

body{background: url('https://iso.500px.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/andre_cover.jpg');background-size:450px; background-repeat: no-repeat;}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

**[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/L1dsaqL3/6/)**

**Edit 2:**

If you don't want background then put image inside give.

```
<div>
<img src="https://iso.500px.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/andre_cover.jpg" width="450px" />
</div>
```

**[New Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L1dsaqL3/7/)**

Comment: Doesn't work with Chrome 48. Works nice with Firefox, though.

Comment: The second solutions fits me. Is there any possibilities that can be done without background image

Comment: Thanks @ketan thats what i was expecting :)

Comment: @ketan the solution is not working with safari do you have any clue y

Comment: @Benjamin I am using 5.1.7 version of safari and it's working. http://i.stack.imgur.com/YdghV.png

Comment: My version of safari is Version 9.0.3 (11601.4.4)

Comment: I can see latest version is.  Safari for Windows Latest version 5.1.7

Comment: I use mac osx el capiton

Answer (score 0):

You could try to mask it, take a look here: https://webkit.org/blog/181/css-masks/

Comment: I guess you took my question in wrong way. I wanted to show the image transparent other than the parts in sphere.

Comment: In that case use a transparency mask for those areas, however that is not yet deeply supported across browsers.

Comment: You could use 2 images, one transparent, and the other one just the sphere overlapped where you want it ...